# How can I display a system tray icon for Node.js window service.?

Tags: node.js, windows-services

I had created a windows service in node.js and now I had a requirement in which I had to create a system tray icon which can show the status of my service. If service is running, I want to show kind of a green dot and if the service is stopped I want to show a red dot. I am not able to figure out how to achieve that.

I had tried using some of the JS packages like "systray", "systray2", "tray" but not able to create any tray icon.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am new to creating windows service, before I was a front-end developer so have some practice in JS. So I chose node.js to create a windows service but not able to find any good library or package and don't have any code written yet. Need help that how can I create windows system tray icon of my windows service.